# Why do-release-upgrade does not show 14.04 even if it was officially released?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I do have 12.04 LTS and hearing that 14.04 LTS was released I (wrongly) assumed that I will be able to upgrade machines using the standard distribution upgrade path.

Still it seems that 'sudo do-release-upgrade' does not see any new release.

Why it doesn't show it and when is this going to be visible?

Obviously, I do not want to force the usage of development / unstable versions.

Also, considering the 14.04 was released on April 17, why it was released when it was not considered "stable" yet? ... there is something in the release process that doesn't make sense to me :p

Comment: Try `sudo update-manager -d`.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 14.04LTS has not been officially released for 12.04LTS users. This is scheduled for July 24th 2014, when the first dot-release (service pack) becomes available as Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Upgrading a whole distribution of software is entirely different from just upgrading an OS like Windows or OS X. When you upgrade Ubuntu, all your software is upgraded and is supposed to work without any configuration or that sort of thing. This makes the upgrade process much more difficult than a clean install and thus requires more time to develop. So the LTS-upgrade process is still in development even if 14.04LTS itself is stable.

This is why LTS users are never presented with an upgrade path until a few months after the new version is released.